# Error messages not displayed after calling Page_ClientValidate JS function

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am working on an ASP .Net web application.
One of my ASPX page contains a custom TextBox control.

3 validation controls are applied to the TextBox :

- 1 RequiredFieldValidator

  - ErrorMessage="*"
  - Display="Dynamic"
  - ValidationGroup="IdentityRequired"
- 2 CompareValidator :

  - ErrorMessage="*"
  - ValidationGroup="Identity"

A custom JS function is executed when form is submitted.
The custom JS function contains the 2 following statements :

```
var b_RegExp = window.Page_ClientValidate('Identity');
var b_Required = window.Page_ClientValidate('IdentityRequired');
```

When b_Required is false then a star is displayed caused by the RequiredFieldValidator => OK !
When b_RegExp is false no star is displayed => KO !
Can anyone explain to me what is wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the last call to window.Page_ClientValidate determines the error messages to display.
No error messages (star) are displayed even if errors have been detected in the Identity group because the last call to window.Page_ClientValidate detects no error in the IdentityRequired group.

So I have changed my two JS statements as follows :

```
var b_Required = window.Page_ClientValidate('IdentityRequired');
var b_RegExp = false;
if (b_Required)
    b_RegExp = window.Page_ClientValidate('Identity');
```

And I have added Display="Dynamic" to the markup of my 2 CompareValidator controls.